# ITC.apps.validation.pre release build missing

Tags: ios7, app-store-connect, xcode5.1

I uploaded my app to the iTunesConnect via Application Loader then I hit the "Submit for Review" button and I got this error: "ITC.apps.validation.pre release build missing". What is this exactly? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just had the same thing - I tried re-uploading the app via xcode but it led to an error saying the binary already exists. I logged out and logged back in to itunes connect. After that I discovered a "+" button within the "Build" section. After clicking the "+" I was able to select the uploaded app, which then removed this error message.

Maybe it helps...

Comment: I just did that before I read this answers but thanks anyway and your answer is true ! :)

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, helped a lot. Hail the king of UI - precious, sweet Apple

Answer (score 8):

Go on the same page to the section "Build" and select your uploaded app. Click on "Save" and then on "Submit for Review" This is new on itunes connect.

Comment: This did it for me. I had uploaded the binary from Xcode, but somehow it wasn't selected (even though it was the only binary available). The curious thing is, this only happened with one of two apps I was attempting to update simultaneously (paid & free version). The other one, I could submit without problems.